# Task scheduler not running (Server)

Tags: windows, batch, scheduled-task, windows-server-2008-r2

I have written a simple bat file to copy .txt files from one drive into another one. I want this to run everyday at this time but the problem is when I'm not logged in to the server the task does not run. I have also selected the "Run whether logged in or not".

```
--- script ---
@echo off
cd\
cd blah\blah\blah
copy *.txt Q:\blahdrive /y
Exit
--- script ---
```

Comment: Provide the version of the windows server you are using. BTW, I feel that it is more a question for Server-Fault than SO

Comment: Windows server 2008 R2 Standard

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell but are you trying to copy files to a Network Share or Mapped Drive?  Q is pretty high for a local disk so I'm assuming that's what you are doing.  Mapped Drives/Network Shares only exist when you are logged into the machine.  The connection to the drive is dropped once you logoff.  Therefore you cannot copy files to a mapped drive unless a user is logged in.

However, you can use UNC file paths to the server or you can use the NET USE command to setup a temporary session to the drive.  UNC path is probably the easiest to implement.

Comment: ^This. Sometimes batch doesn't like UNC paths so much though, so if you need to use `net use` just put it right after @echo off: `net use Q: \\blahserver\blahdrive /user:domain\username password`

Comment: Agreed, Mapped Drive support without an open profile in Windows pretty much sucks. To be safe always hit it with NET USE.

Comment: Q is also the default AppV/softgrid drive, and you can't copy things like that to it.